# Problem on installing alink MT7601U Wireless Adapter on centos 7

Tags: centos, wifi

I want to install driver for alink MT7601U Wireless Adapter on centos 7, but i can't do it because it has error.
I have updated the `yum` with `yum update`, and after that i reboot my system.
Now I want to install the this driver but i encounter with this Error message.

```
    # make
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory `/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory `/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/tools'
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/tools/bin2h
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64/build SUBDIRS=/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64'
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.o
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c: In function ‘announce_802_3_packet’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c:331:16: warning: unused variable ‘pAd’ [-Wunused-variable]
  RTMP_ADAPTER *pAd = (RTMP_ADAPTER *)pAdSrc;
                ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c: In function ‘STA_MonPktSend’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c:399:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has t                              ype ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
         DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_ERROR, ("%s : Size is too large! (%d)\n", __FUNCTION__, pRxBlk->DataSize + sizeof(wlan_ng_prism2_header)));
         ^
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../sta/assoc.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../sta/auth.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../sta/auth_rsp.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../sta/sync.o
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../sta/sync.c: In function ‘PeerBeacon’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../sta/sync.c:2181:12: warning: passing argument 8 of ‘StaAddMacTableEntry’ from incompatible pointer typ                              e [enabled by default]
            ie_list->CapabilityInfo) == FALSE)
            ^
In file included from /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/include/rt_config.h:59:0,
                 from /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../sta/sync.c:28:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/include/rtmp.h:7892:9: note: expected ‘struct IE_LISTS *’ but argument is of type ‘struct BCN_IE_LIST *’
 BOOLEAN StaAddMacTableEntry(
         ^
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../sta/sanity.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../sta/rtmp_data.o
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../sta/rtmp_data.c: In function ‘STAHandleRxDataFrame’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../sta/rtmp_data.c:523:4: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘MacTableLookup’ from incompatible pointer type                               [enabled by default]
    pEntry = MacTableLookup(pAd, &pHeader->Addr2);
    ^
In file included from /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/include/rt_config.h:59:0,
                 from /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../sta/rtmp_data.c:28:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/include/rtmp.h:8429:18: note: expected ‘UCHAR *’ but argument is of type ‘UCHAR (*)[6]’
 MAC_TABLE_ENTRY *MacTableLookup(RTMP_ADAPTER *pAd, UCHAR *pAddr);
                  ^
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../sta/connect.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../sta/wpa.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c: In function ‘RTMPIoctlRF’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:5306:7: warning: format ‘%X’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 5 has                               type ‘LONG’ [-Wformat=]
       sprintf(msg+strlen(msg), "BANK%d_R%02d:%02X  ", bank_Id, rfId, rfValue);
       ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:5359:3: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘RtmpDrvAllRFPrint’ from incompatible pointer typ                              e [enabled by default]
   RtmpDrvAllRFPrint(NULL, msg, strlen(msg));
   ^
In file included from /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/include/rt_config.h:64:0,
                 from /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:28:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/include/rt_os_util.h:668:6: note: expected ‘UINT32 *’ but argument is of type ‘PSTRING’
 VOID RtmpDrvAllRFPrint(
      ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:5209:22: warning: unused variable ‘rf_bank’ [-Wunused-variable]
  UCHAR    regRF = 0, rf_bank = 0;
                      ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c: In function ‘RtmpIoctl_rt_ioctl_siwgenie’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:7610:13: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     eid_ptr = pAd->StaCfg.pWpaAssocIe;
             ^
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/crypt_md5.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/crypt_sha2.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/crypt_hmac.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/crypt_aes.o
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/crypt_aes.c: In function ‘AES_Key_Wrap’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/crypt_aes.c:1459:6: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
      DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_ERROR, ("AES_Key_Wrap: allocate %d bytes memory failure.\n", sizeof(UINT8)*PlainTextLength));
      ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/crypt_aes.c: In function ‘AES_Key_Unwrap’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/crypt_aes.c:1554:6: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
      DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_ERROR, ("AES_Key_Unwrap: allocate %d bytes memory failure.\n", sizeof(UINT8)*PlainLength));
      ^
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/crypt_arc4.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/mlme.o
In file included from /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/include/rtmp_os.h:44:0,
                 from /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/include/rtmp_comm.h:75,
                 from /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/include/rt_config.h:33,
                 from /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/mlme.c:28:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/mlme.c: In function ‘MlmeResetRalinkCounters’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/mlme.c:544:7: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
       (UINT32)&pAd->RalinkCounters.OneSecEnd -
       ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/include/os/rt_linux.h:473:76: note: in definition of macro ‘NdisZeroMemory’
 #define NdisZeroMemory(Destination, Length)         memset(Destination, 0, Length)
                                                                            ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/mlme.c:545:7: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
       (UINT32)&pAd->RalinkCounters.OneSecStart);
       ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/include/os/rt_linux.h:473:76: note: in definition of macro ‘NdisZeroMemory’
 #define NdisZeroMemory(Destination, Length)         memset(Destination, 0, Length)
                                                                            ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/mlme.c: In function ‘AsicRxAntEvalTimeout’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/mlme.c:5201:45: warning: unused variable ‘rssi_diff’ [-Wunused-variable]
  CHAR   larger = -127, rssi0, rssi1, rssi2, rssi_diff;
                                             ^
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_wep.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/action.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.o
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.c: In function ‘CmdRspEventCallbackHandle’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.c:2509:8: warning: unused variable ‘Ret’ [-Wunused-variable]
  INT32 Ret;
        ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.c: In function ‘StopDmaTx’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.c:2684:8: warning: unused variable ‘IdleNums’ [-Wunused-variable]
  UINT8 IdleNums = 0;
        ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.c:2682:20: warning: unused variable ‘UsbCfg’ [-Wunused-variable]
  USB_DMA_CFG_STRUC UsbCfg;
                    ^
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_init.o
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_init.c: In function ‘NICInitAsicFromEEPROM’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_init.c:981:9: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
  USHORT i;
         ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_init.c: In function ‘NICInitializeAdapter’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_init.c:1292:22: warning: unused variable ‘GloCfg’ [-Wunused-variable]
  WPDMA_GLO_CFG_STRUC GloCfg;
                      ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_init.c: In function ‘NICInitializeAsic’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_init.c:1367:11: warning: unused variable ‘KeyIdx’ [-Wunused-variable]
  USHORT   KeyIdx;
           ^
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_init_inf.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_tkip.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_aes.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_sync.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/eeprom.o
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/eeprom.c: In function ‘RtmpChipOpsEepromHook’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/eeprom.c:34:9: warning: unused variable ‘e2p_csr’ [-Wunused-variable]
  UINT32 e2p_csr;
         ^
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_sanity.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.o
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.c: In function ‘Set_DebugFunc_Proc’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.c:1084:2: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘const char *’ [-Wformat=]
  DBGPRINT_S(RT_DEBUG_TRACE, ("Set RTDebugFunc = 0x%x\n",__FUNCTION__, RTDebugFunc));
  ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.c:1084:2: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.c: In function ‘set_rf’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.c:5730:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 5 has type ‘UCHAR *’ [-Wformat=]
   rv = sscanf(arg, "%d-%d-%x", &(bank_id), &(rf_id), &(rf_val));
   ^
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_cfg.o
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_cfg.c: In function ‘wmode_valid_and_correct’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_cfg.c:279:8: warning: unused variable ‘mode’ [-Wunused-variable]
  UCHAR mode = *wmode;
        ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_cfg.c: At top level:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_cfg.c:264:16: warning: ‘wmode_valid’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static BOOLEAN wmode_valid(RTMP_ADAPTER *pAd, enum WIFI_MODE wmode)
                ^
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_wpa.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_radar.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/spectrum.o
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/spectrum.c: In function ‘PeerMeasureReportAction’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/spectrum.c:1972:3: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
   DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_ERROR, ("%s unable to alloc memory for measure report buffer (size=%d).\n", __FUNCTION__, sizeof(MEASURE_RPI_REPORT)));
   ^
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_timer.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/rt_channel.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_profile.o
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_profile.c: In function ‘rtmp_read_multest_from_file’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_profile.c:2671:23: warning: unused variable ‘pWdsEntry’ [-Wunused-variable]
  PRT_802_11_WDS_ENTRY pWdsEntry;
                       ^
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_asic.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/scan.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/cmm_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/uapsd.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/ps.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../rate_ctrl/ra_ctrl.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../rate_ctrl/alg_legacy.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../rate_ctrl/alg_ags.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../chips/rtmp_chip.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/txpower.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../mac/rtmp_mac.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../mgmt/mgmt_hw.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../mgmt/mgmt_entrytb.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../phy/rtmp_phy.o
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../phy/rtmp_phy.c: In function ‘NICInitBBP’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../phy/rtmp_phy.c:61:8: warning: unused variable ‘R0’ [-Wunused-variable]
  UCHAR R0 = 0xff;
        ^
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../phy/rlt_phy.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../phy/rlt_rf.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/ba_action.o
In file included from /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/include/rtmp_os.h:44:0,
                 from /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/include/rtmp_comm.h:75,
                 from /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/include/rt_config.h:33,
                 from /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/ba_action.c:30:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/ba_action.c: In function ‘convert_reordering_packet_to_preAMSDU_or_802_3_packet’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/include/os/rt_linux.h:886:34: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
   ((RTPKT_TO_OSPKT(_pkt))->tail) = (PUCHAR)((_start) + (_len))
                                  ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/include/os/rt_linux.h:929:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘SET_OS_PKT_DATATAIL’
  SET_OS_PKT_DATATAIL(__pRxPkt, __pData, __DataSize);      \
  ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/ba_action.c:1574:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘RTMP_OS_PKT_INIT’
  RTMP_OS_PKT_INIT(pRxBlk->pRxPacket,
  ^
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../mgmt/mgmt_ht.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../common/rt_os_util.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/sta_ioctl.o
  CC [M]  /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.o
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘RtmpOsUsDelay’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:179:8: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
  ULONG i;
        ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘duplicate_pkt’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:497:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘memmove’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   NdisMoveMemory(skb->tail, pHeader802_3, HdrLen);
   ^
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/string.h:4:0,
                 from include/linux/string.h:18,
                 from include/linux/bitmap.h:8,
                 from include/linux/cpumask.h:11,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpumask.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/msr.h:10,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:20,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:22,
                 from include/linux/thread_info.h:54,
                 from include/linux/preempt.h:9,
                 from include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/include/os/rt_linux.h:31,
                 from /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/include/rtmp_os.h:44,
                 from /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/include/rtmp_comm.h:75,
                 from /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:32:
./arch/x86/include/asm/string_64.h:58:7: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘sk_buff_data_t’
 void *memmove(void *dest, const void *src, size_t count);
       ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:499:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘memmove’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   NdisMoveMemory(skb->tail, pData, DataSize);
   ^
In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/string.h:4:0,
                 from include/linux/string.h:18,
                 from include/linux/bitmap.h:8,
                 from include/linux/cpumask.h:11,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpumask.h:4,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/msr.h:10,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:20,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:22,
                 from include/linux/thread_info.h:54,
                 from include/linux/preempt.h:9,
                 from include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/include/os/rt_linux.h:31,
                 from /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/include/rtmp_os.h:44,
                 from /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/include/rtmp_comm.h:75,
                 from /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:32:
./arch/x86/include/asm/string_64.h:58:7: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘sk_buff_data_t’
 void *memmove(void *dest, const void *src, size_t count);
       ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘ClonePacket’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:650:20: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
   pClonedPkt->tail = pClonedPkt->data + pClonedPkt->len;
                    ^
In file included from /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/include/rtmp_os.h:44:0,
                 from /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/include/rtmp_comm.h:75,
                 from /qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:32:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘RtmpOsPktInit’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/include/os/rt_linux.h:886:34: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
   ((RTPKT_TO_OSPKT(_pkt))->tail) = (PUCHAR)((_start) + (_len))
                                  ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:669:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘SET_OS_PKT_DATATAIL’
  SET_OS_PKT_DATATAIL(pRxPkt, pData, DataSize);
  ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘wlan_802_11_to_802_3_packet’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:695:15: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
  pOSPkt->tail = pOSPkt->data + pOSPkt->len;
               ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘__RtmpOSFSInfoChange’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:1121:20: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int’ from type ‘kuid_t’
   pOSFSInfo->fsuid = current_fsuid();
                    ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:1122:20: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int’ from type ‘kgid_t’
   pOSFSInfo->fsgid = current_fsgid();
                    ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘RtmpDrvAllRFPrint’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:2052:4: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘file_w->f_op->write’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
    file_w->f_op->write(file_w, pBuf, BufLen, &file_w->f_pos);
    ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:2052:4: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘UINT32 *’
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:2037:22: warning: unused variable ‘macValue’ [-Wunused-variable]
  UINT32 macAddr = 0, macValue = 0;
                      ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:2037:9: warning: unused variable ‘macAddr’ [-Wunused-variable]
  UINT32 macAddr = 0, macValue = 0;
         ^
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘RtmpOSIRQRelease’:
/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:2173:21: warning: unused variable ‘net_dev’ [-Wunused-variable]
  struct net_device *net_dev = (struct net_device *)pNetDev;
                     ^
make[2]: *** [/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/qomDB/LinuxSTA_wifi/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64'
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

I really don't know how can i solve it. please Help me

Comment: This is hacky, but it might work for you: https://github.com/ashaffer/rt3573sta/issues/8 I recommend reading whole thread.

Comment: Fiisch Thanks for your reply, but when i use modprobe RT2780STA, it can't find the module.

Comment: welcome to U&L , are you trying to compile this driver https://github.com/kuba-moo/mt7601u ?

Comment: The only obvious problem I see in your compile output is `error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int’ from type ‘kuid_t’` and one other following few lines below it. Workarounds to these are discussed in what I have linked. Running modprobe on rt2870 - totally diferent module than you were building - makes no sense.